# Project Vaadin with Maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, vaadin

I am busy developing a Vaadin with Maven project. I would like to integrate Hibernate with this project, but I can't do it.
I've added the dependencies and libraries, but Hibernate does not work.
This is the pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.bd</groupId>
  <artifactId>achrefvaadin</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Vaadin Web Application</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <vaadin.version>6.7.0</vaadin.version>
    <gwt.version>2.3.0</gwt.version>
    <gwt.plugin.version>2.2.0</gwt.plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>




      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.24</version>
        <configuration>
          <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
          <stopKey>achrefvaadin</stopKey>
          <!-- Redeploy every x seconds if changes are detected, 0 for no automatic redeployment -->
          <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <!-- make sure Jetty also finds the widgetset -->
          <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/achrefvaadin</contextPath>
            <baseResource implementation="org.mortbay.resource.ResourceCollection">
              <!-- Workaround for Maven/Jetty issue http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-680 -->
              <!-- <resources>src/main/webapp,${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</resources> -->
              <resourcesAsCSV>src/main/webapp,${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</resourcesAsCSV>
            </baseResource>
          </webAppConfig>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
      <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>vaadin-addons</id>
      <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
      <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
       <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific when you are saying "it does not work"? I guess you have a version clash. I guess it should be enough to include hibernate-entitymanager because Maven will resolve the other three artifacts on its own.

Comment: in first i create archtype-vaadin-clean then i added the dependencies of hibernate, just i do this, how i work hibernate??

Comment: Ok, but have you tried to delete the dependencies hibernate-core, hibernate-annotations and hibernate-commons-annotations? As I said, they should be resolved all by hibernate-entitymanager.

Comment: i don't delete   the dependencies hibernate-core, hibernate-annotations and hibernate-commons-annotations, how i resolve the hibernate-entitymanager

Answer (score 1):

Try this pom:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.bd</groupId>
  <artifactId>achrefvaadin</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Vaadin Web Application</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <vaadin.version>6.7.0</vaadin.version>
    <gwt.version>2.3.0</gwt.version>
    <gwt.plugin.version>2.2.0</gwt.plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>




      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.24</version>
        <configuration>
          <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
          <stopKey>achrefvaadin</stopKey>
          <!-- Redeploy every x seconds if changes are detected, 0 for no automatic redeployment -->
          <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <!-- make sure Jetty also finds the widgetset -->
          <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/achrefvaadin</contextPath>
            <baseResource implementation="org.mortbay.resource.ResourceCollection">
              <!-- Workaround for Maven/Jetty issue http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-680 -->
              <!-- <resources>src/main/webapp,${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</resources> -->
              <resourcesAsCSV>src/main/webapp,${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</resourcesAsCSV>
            </baseResource>
          </webAppConfig>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
      <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>vaadin-addons</id>
      <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
      <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

If you are including just hibernate-entitymanager Maven will download hibernate-core, hibernate-annotations and hibernate-commons-annotations on it's own in the right version.

Comment: some problem, perhaps the problem of the hibernate file, you have exemple of hibernate file?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Could you rephrase your answer. And describe the what exactly the problem is.

Comment: i tried your solution but some problem, the hibernate not work

Comment: But what EXACTLY is the problem? Do you get a stacktrace? Any error message?

Comment: i would do simple project with maven vaadin hibernate spring, but i can't?